# Parsing invalid Unicode JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8

i have a problematic json string contains some funky unicode characters

```
"test":{"foo":"Ig0s\x5C/k\x5C/4jRk"}}
```

and if I convert using python

```
import json
s = r'{"test":{"foo":"Ig0s\x5C/k\x5C/4jRk"}}'
json.loads(s) 
# Error..
```

If I can accept to skip/lose the value of these unicode characters, what is the best way to make my `json.loads(s)` works?

Comment: It seems you are missing some slashes. When I add the slashes, it works just fine. `In [11]: s = r'{"test":{"foo":"Ig0s\\x5C/k\\x5C/4jRk"}}'

In [12]: json.loads(s)
Out[12]: {u'test': {u'foo': u'Ig0s\\x5C/k\\x5C/4jRk'}}
`

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: Yeah, sure, then you just escaped the escapes. That's not the point though, is it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have JSON; that can be interpreted directly as Python instead. Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = r'{"test":{"foo":"Ig0s\x5C/k\x5C/4jRk"}}'
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
{'test': {'foo': 'Ig0s\\/k\\/4jRk'}}
```

The `\x5C` is a single backslash, doubled in the Python literal string representation here. The actual string value is:

```
>>> print _['test']['foo']
Ig0s\/k\/4jRk
```

This parses the input as Python source, but only allows for literal values; strings, `None`, `True`, `False`, numbers and containers (lists, tuples, dictionaries).

This method is slower than `json.loads()` because it does part of the parse-tree processing in pure Python code.

Another approach would be to use a regular expression to replace the `\xhh` escape codes with JSON `\uhhhh` codes:

```
import re

escape_sequence = re.compile(r'\\x([a-fA-F0-9]{2})')

def repair(string):
    return escape_sequence.sub(r'\\u00\1', string)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(repair(s))
{u'test': {u'foo': u'Ig0s\\/k\\/4jRk'}}
```

If you can repair the *source* producing this value to output actual JSON instead that'd be a *much* better solution.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval()` might fail on JSON literals such as `true`, `false`, `null`. The regex may fail if `x..` is escaped by even number of backslashes. You could [use 'string-escape' encoding instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23318908/4279)

Answer (score 1):

If the rest of the string apart from invalid `\x5c` is a JSON then you could use `string-escape` encoding to decode `'\x5c into backslashes:

```
>>> import json
>>> s = r'{"test":{"foo":"Ig0s\x5C/k\x5C/4jRk"}}'
>>> json.loads(s.decode('string-escape')) 
{u'test': {u'foo': u'Ig0s/k/4jRk'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late for the party, but we were seeing a similar issue, to be precise this one [Logstash JSON input with escaped double quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46848472/logstash-json-input-with-escaped-double-quote), just for \xXX.

There `JS.stringify` created such (per [specification](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)) invalid json texts.

The solution is to simply replace the `\x` by `\u00`, as unicode escaped characters are allowed, while ASCII escaped characters are not.

```
import json
s = r'{"test":{"foo":"Ig0s\x5C/k\x5C/4jRk"}}'
s = s.replace("\\x", "\\u00")
json.loads(s)
```