# Logstash JSON input with escaped double quote

Tags: json, apache-kafka, logstash

I'm trying to send json strings to logstash and then kafka, but I keep experiencing json parse failures due to the escaped double quotes in my json file.

I've tried a bunch of different combinations of the replace, but none of it works. I'm not sure if

1. The error occurs already in the input side of the config, so it's not continuing to the filter part
2. I'm just not replacing the strings correctly

I am getting a json as :

```
{"message": "This is a \"string with quote"}
```

My logstash conf is:

```
input {
  tcp {
    codec => json { charset => "UTF-8" }
    port => 10000
  }
}

filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
  }
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["@version", "@timestamp", "host", "port"]
    gsub => [
      # replace all backslashes + double quote with space
     'body', '\\"', ' '
    ]
  }
} 

output {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
    codec => json {charset => "UTF-8"}
    topic_id => 'logstash_logs'
  }

file {
    path => "/usr/share/logstash/test.log"
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

My rubydebug log is:

```
{
    "message" => "{\"message\": \"This is a \"string with quote\"}",
       "tags" => [
        [0] "_jsonparsefailure"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is the full source message?

Comment: The actual message I'm receiving are news articles from premium news source. An excerpt looks like this: {"an":"AFNWS00020150624eb6o0006h","body":"The fair is intended to show the potential of renewable energies, ... \n\n\"We are electrifying rural areas that are a long way from the national grid\", she said. \"We have been prioritizing solar panels to provide electricity for social infrastructures such as schools and hospitals\".}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_jsonparsefailure` is diagnostic here, that tells me that it was the `json {}` filter that failed. Since logstash [is using their own parsing gem](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-json/blob/master/lib/logstash/filters/json.rb#L4) that uses [the jrjackson gem](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/jrjackson/0.3.8), you can test some of that parsing if you have jruby handy.

```
  JrJackson::Ruby.parse(data, options)

rescue JrJackson::ParseError => e
  raise LogStash::Json::ParserError.new(e.message)
end
```

That's the segment of code that's failing your parse, so this is likely a bug in the jrjackson parser. If you can get a clean reproduction, [consider reporting it as an issue on the gem](https://github.com/guyboertje/jrjackson/issues). If not, this is a candidate for reporting on [the logstash-filter-json project's issue-tracker](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-json/issues).

Working around this will require you to "fix" the log-line before its parsed. That is some gnarly regex.